# Maven adding layers.idx and other spring classes automatically to the war file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, maven

I am building a war using maven (`mvn clean install`), the build is successful but the problem is few spring-boot related jars are getting missed in the war file(I checked using `jar tf` command) and instead of that many other springboot related classes and layer.idx file is getting added. How to remove these so that they are not included in the war and all other spring related dependencies are added properly. I tried deleting the local maven repo but it didn't worked.
Here is my pom.xml -

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.meco.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>test-service</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>devTest</name>
  <description>Development-Project</description>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
  </parent>
  
  <dependencies>
  
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    </dependency>
        
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
       <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.inject/javax.inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
        <artifactId>hk2-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-server -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.json/javax.json-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.json.bind/javax.json.bind-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.json.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json.bind-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.sshd/sshd-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.sshd</groupId>
        <artifactId>sshd-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.sshd/sshd-common -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.sshd</groupId>
        <artifactId>sshd-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <!-- <scope>test</scope> -->
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler/ecj -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
        <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    
  </dependencies>
  
  <build>
    <finalName>demon</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <generateBackupPoms>false</generateBackupPoms>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <release>11</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

These files are getting added unnecessarily - (Output of jar tf demon.war) [not the complete output]

```
org/
org/springframework/
org/springframework/boot/
org/springframework/boot/loader/
org/springframework/boot/loader/ClassPathIndexFile.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/ExecutableArchiveLauncher.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/JarLauncher.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/LaunchedURLClassLoader$DefinePackageCallType.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/LaunchedURLClassLoader$UseFastConnectionExceptionsEnumeration.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/LaunchedURLClassLoader.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/Launcher.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/MainMethodRunner.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/PropertiesLauncher$1.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/PropertiesLauncher$ArchiveEntryFilter.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/PropertiesLauncher$ClassPathArchives.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/PropertiesLauncher$PrefixMatchingArchiveFilter.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/PropertiesLauncher.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/WarLauncher.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/
org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/Archive$Entry.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/Archive$EntryFilter.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/Archive.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/ExplodedArchive$AbstractIterator.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/ExplodedArchive$ArchiveIterator.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/ExplodedArchive$EntryIterator.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/ExplodedArchive$FileEntry.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/ExplodedArchive$SimpleJarFileArchive.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/ExplodedArchive.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/JarFileArchive$AbstractIterator.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/JarFileArchive$EntryIterator.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/JarFileArchive$JarFileEntry.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/JarFileArchive$NestedArchiveIterator.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/JarFileArchive.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/data/
org/springframework/boot/loader/data/RandomAccessData.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/data/RandomAccessDataFile$1.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/data/RandomAccessDataFile$DataInputStream.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/data/RandomAccessDataFile$FileAccess.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/data/RandomAccessDataFile.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/AbstractJarFile$JarFileType.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/AbstractJarFile.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/AsciiBytes.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/Bytes.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/CentralDirectoryEndRecord$1.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/CentralDirectoryEndRecord$Zip64End.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/CentralDirectoryEndRecord$Zip64Locator.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/CentralDirectoryEndRecord.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/CentralDirectoryFileHeader.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/CentralDirectoryParser.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/CentralDirectoryVisitor.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/FileHeader.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/Handler.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarEntry.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarEntryCertification.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarEntryFilter.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarFile$1.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarFile$JarEntryEnumeration.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarFile.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarFileEntries$1.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarFileEntries$EntryIterator.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarFileEntries.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarFileWrapper.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarURLConnection$1.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarURLConnection$JarEntryName.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarURLConnection.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/StringSequence.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/ZipInflaterInputStream.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jarmode/
org/springframework/boot/loader/jarmode/JarMode.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jarmode/JarModeLauncher.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jarmode/TestJarMode.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/util/
org/springframework/boot/loader/util/SystemPropertyUtils.class
WEB-INF/lib-provided/
WEB-INF/lib-provided/javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-jarmode-layertools-2.5.2.jar
WEB-INF/layers.idx
```

I don't know why spring-boot-jarmode-layertools-2.5.2.jar is getting added and few other important jars which are part of the project are missing. These jars are missing -

```
spring-boot-starter-2.5.2.jar
spring-boot-starter-jersey-2.5.2.jar
spring-boot-starter-json-2.5.2.jar
spring-boot-starter-logging-2.5.2.jar
spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.5.2.jar
spring-boot-starter-validation-2.5.2.jar
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you don't need to execute `install` because you don't need the artifact in your local repository. You should execute `package`.

Second you have some plugins that are not needed. (Why did you change the pom.xml that Spring Boot Initializer generated?)

Remove

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <release>11</release>
            </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

Then you have dependencies that will come from the starters anyway

You can remove everything that has the comment

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/<xy> -->
```

It looks like you want to use JPA so add the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa dependency`.

Comment: Thank you. I removed the plugins and then it worked.

Comment: If my answer was helpful please accept it. Thank you